# I am struggling to have a 24 hour Mysql Connection from SSIS

Tags: mysql, ssis, ssis-2014

I have an SSIS job that connects to mySQL db, it runs from 01:00 to 13:00 daily for every 15 minutes, but it return Zero rows once it hits 02:00 and does not fail and I have to run the SSIS job for it to start working propely again, I want to know if there is something I can change to fix this issue?

I have tried changing HTTP keep Alive to 0, but the issue still remains

Comment: Check the MySQL logs? Maybe MySQL killed the connection for idle time?

Comment: So does the SSIS package run continuously from 01:00 to 13:00? Or is there a job that runs every 15 minutes that executes the package?